# Network inconsistencies between Windows and NAS from one computer but not from other

Tags: windows, networking, nas

I just moved to a new apartment and I'm setting up me and my gf's computer, everything is plugged the same way and it seems I'm getting very spotty connection to the NAS but she doesn't. I have tried using the same cable she is using and I still get the same issues.

Transfer speeds will start and very quickly drop to 0 and sit like that for maybe 20-40 seconds then resume, then drop again multiple times until the transfer is done, I'm testing with 3 files of about 1gb each. I also sometimes have issues accessing the network drive, when I double click on it it will freeze my window and will not open until maybe 1 minute later.

I'm using the same computer I was using before in my old apartment and it worked fine. I also tried transferring files from my computer directly to hers and it all works just fine, so it seems that is just a problem between mine and the NAS.

Here is a screenshot of the transfer, it shows that the transfer speed has slowed down and not stopped but in reality, it stops completely for like 30 seconds.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCeAM.jpg

Here is a graph from the NAS transfer activity during the same transfer. As you can see the transfer stops completely multiple times.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ueYP9.jpg

I have tried with 2 different routers and 1 switch and I still get the same issue.

Thinking about formatting my PC but what to see if I can find a solution before doing that.

Any ideas on what I could try?

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: I already tried with multiple ports, routers and with a switch. Using the same port will work fine with my gf's computer but not with mine.

Comment: Adding routers between you & the NAS only slows data down. 1) Suggest you delete your Network Connection & create a new one. 2) Does your PC have a separate network card or is it integrated on the motherboard? 2A) If separate, what card is it? 2B) If integrated, what motherboard is it? 3) what make & model switch do you use between your PC and the NAS? 4) What's the make & model of the NAS? Click [edit] to put your facts in your question, as well as your findings in the comment above. Please don't use Add Comment to answer us; your findings, facts, theories go in the Question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up formatting my computer and now the NAS was not accessible at all.

Finally I did a soft reset using the back button in my WD PR4100 NAS and now everything works fine.

Its so odd  that was working fine for one computer and not for the other one... but I'm happy its over!